# Is this property true for all $p$ or for all primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

In my textbook the following property is stated:

> Let $p$ be a prime number. For any $a_1,...,a_k\in \mathbb Z$ we have that:
> $$p|a_1...a_k \implies \exists i\in\{1,...,k\}:p|a_i$$
> In particular, for any $a,b \in \mathbb Z$:
>
> - $p|ab \implies (p|a \vee p|b)$
> - $p|a^k \implies p|a$

I was able to prove this for but, In my proof, I never used the fact that $p$ is prime. Because of this, I don't know if my proof is valid but this got me wondering: Is this property also valid for any $p$ or only if $p$ is prime?

Edit: I'll show the proof I made for this.

---

Let $p$ be a prime number and $a_1,...,a_k \in \mathbb Z$ such that:

$$p|\prod_{n=1}^k a_n$$

The proof is by contradiction. Let's assume that $\forall i \in \{1,...,k\}, p \not | a_i$

Now, let's use mathematical induction:

- $p \not | a_1$
- Now let's assume that $p \not | \prod_{n=1}^{k-1} a_n$:

We have that $p \not | a_k \iff \gcd(p,a_k) = 1$ and $p \not | \prod_{n=1}^{k-1} a_n \iff \gcd(p,\prod_{n=1}^{k-1} a_n)=1$.

Since $\gcd(p,\prod_{n=1}^{k-1} a_n)=1$ and $\gcd(p,a_k) = 1$ we conclude that: $\gcd(p,a_k \cdot \prod_{n=1}^{k-1} a_n)=1 \iff p \not | \prod_{n=1}^{k} a_n$

This is a contradiction, hence $\exists i \in \{1,...,k\}: p | a_i$

Comment: You should write your proof.

Comment: Note that $4|2^3$ does NOT imply $4|2$.

Comment: I'll edit the post to include the proof. @AsemAbdelraouf

Comment: The fact that $p$ is prime is crucial. For example, $4\mid 2^2$ but $4\not\mid 2$.

Comment: $6\mid 6$ but $6\not\mid 2$ and $6\not\mid 3.$ This generalizes to any composite $p.$

Comment: done @AsemAbdelraouf

Comment: The claim $p\!\not|\; a \iff \gcd(p,a) = 1$ is false for general $p$ (It is true  when $p$ is a prime)

Comment: Definitely not true for all natural numbers.  Consider $6|2\cdot 3$.  But $6\not\mid 2$ and $6\not \mid 3$.

Comment: You say $p\not \mid a_k \iff \gcd(p, a_k) = 1$.....  Do you *really* believe that?  $\gcd(6,8) = 2\ne 1$.  Do you really believe that means $6\mid 8$?.... (BTW:  If $p$ is prime then $p|a_k \iff \gcd(p,a_k)$ *is* true but you can't take that for granted.  You will have to prove it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if $p$ is prime.

Let's see counterexamples to this, to

- $n \vert ab \Longrightarrow n \vert a \vee n \vert b.$

If $n = ab,$ then $ab \not \vert a$ and $ab \not \vert b.$ The property works for primes because the prime factors cannot be split into further non 1 prime factors.

- $n \vert a^k \Longrightarrow n \vert a.$ This is not true: suppose $k > 2$ and $n = a^2.$ It follows that this doesn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

$6|6=2\cdot 3$, but $6$ divides neither $3$ nor $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You make the claim that $p\not\mid a_k \iff \gcd(p, a_k) = 1$.

That's clearly false.  Consider $6\not \mid 14$ but $\gcd(6, 14) =2$.

.... The *gyst* of the statement (which is called Euclid's lemma) is that all numbers are composed of indivisible prime "atoms".  If $n|a\cdot b\cdot c$ then the prime atoms of $n$ may be spread across $a,b,$ and $c$ but each individual atom must belong to one of $a,b$ or $c$.

So the statement isn't true.  $6|24 = 3\cdot 8$ but $6\not \mid 3$ and $6\not \mid 8$.  But the prime *atoms* of $6$ are $2$ and $3$.  The $2$ atom is contained in the $8$.  And the $3$ atom is contained in the $3$.

So the question is to prove that if $p$ is prime and $p|\prod a_k$ prove that because $p$ can't "be broken up" that it can't be "spread" between $a$ and $b$ that it must divide and be "contained" entirely in either the $a$ or the $b$.

.....

Note:  $n\not \mid b \iff \gcd(n,b)=1$ is clearly false because $n$ can have some $\gcd(n,b) = d$ and $d|b$ but $n$ could have some "extra atoms" that $b$ doesn't share so we could have $\frac nd\not \mid b$.

But if $p$ is prime then $p\not \mid b \iff \gcd(p,b)$ *is* true because if $\gcd(p, b) \ne 1$ then $p$ and $b$ share some prime atoms in common.  But $p$ itself is a prime atom so the only atom they have in common is $p$ and $p|b$.

So.... formalize and prove that as a Lemma:

> Lemma: If $p$ is prime then $p\not \mid b \iff \gcd(p,b) = 1$.

Then your proof will be better. (there's actually a problem in that you proof assumes that there is only one set of $a_1,....a_k$ whose product is the number.  You must assume it is true for every *possible* set of $k$ numbers and every possible product.)

Hint:  It might be *easier* to prove a stronger more detailed lemma:

> Strong Lemma:  If $p$ is prime then for any integer $b$ either $\gcd(p,b) = 1$ and $p\not \mid b$, or $\gcd(p,b) = p$ and $p \mid b$.  No other option exists.